# Should we create a tag for the Dragon32 yet?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

The [Dragon 32 (and Dragon 64)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_32/64) were British microcomputers from the early 1980s that had a lot in common with the Tandy "CoCo" Color Computers. Not technically a clone but often compatible.

We only have a couple of questions specifically about the Dragons, and a few more that mention them.

Should we wait until we have more questions on them before creating a tag, add the existing CoCo tag to questions about them, or just go ahead and make one now?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, go ahead. If we've got two questions about such a clearly-defined topic (i.e. any future questions on the topic would *obviously* use the tag), then we should definitely have a tag for it.

One question? Maybe, maybe not; how likely is it that we'll have more questions on this topic? Is it a useful tag? But if you've already got two questions, and more to come, definitely. Three or more is a no-brainer.

Answer (score 1):

We should never create tags just for the sake of creating tags.

Tags should always be created on need.  If we get Dragon questions then we should have a tag for them, otherwise there is no point.

Comment: Do you mean when we have a certain number of Dragon questions? We have some. What is the number beyond which there is a point?

Comment: You can create a tag on the first question.  As long as the tag is likely to be used on other questions.  There is no minimum limit.

Comment: @The first one was only [asked a month ago](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/14724) by somebody else. I just asked the second. They've been mentioned a couple of other times but not really the subject of the questions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a clean solution would be to make a "6883 sam based computer" tag and make CoCo as well as Dragon synonyms. After all, both are based on Motorola's SAM design, with the parallel port being the main hardware difference.

Otherwise I'd say just wait.